# How can I extend web module in OpenERP

Tags: python, openerp-8

In web module (addons/web)  exist all of the routes (many of them) in Openerp, for example:

- /
- /web
- /web/login

etc. But I want to extend the web module to create other ways (routes) of clients registration. I created a module web_aaa (for testing) and in a controller I include this (almost all the code copied from web/controllers/main.py class Home):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
import jinja2
import simplejson
import os
import sys

import openerp

from openerp import http

from openerp.http import request, serialize_exception as _serialize_exception

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'views'))
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(path)
else:
    loader = jinja2.PackageLoader('openerp.addons.web', "views")

env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader, autoescape=True)
env.filters["json"] = simplejson.dumps

class Home_aaa(http.Controller):

    #This is a new route
    @http.route('/signup', type='http', auth="none")
    def signup(self, **kw):
        return env.get_template("signup.html").render()
```

Then, **when I start the server with**  **"--load web_aaa"** and lookup for /signup it works fine. **But** all the others routes of web module return 404 Not Found (None werkzeug: 192.168.56.1 - - [10/Nov/2014 19:00:44] "GET /web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -).

And when **I start the server without "--load web_aaa"** all the routes of web module works great, **but** web_aaa routes not.

My questions are:

1. How can I create a module that create new routes, or extend the web module, specifically his main.py controller?
2. The web module is a server_wide_module, I changed this option in my config file but my web_aaa module doesn't start. How can I include another server wide module?

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I am having the same problem here, but in version 7

Answer (score -1):

Your cant test:

from web.controllers.main import Home

class Home_aaa(Home):

```
http.route('/signup', type='http', auth="none")
def signup(self, **kw):
    return env.get_template("signup.html").render()
```